# How to get values of multiple select in contact form magento?

Tags: magento

I have a code like this on my form.phtml, its a custom multiple select.

```
<select name="projecttype[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="" selected>Select...</option>
    <option value="Kitchen remodeling">Kitchen</option>
    <option value="Refacing">Reface</option>
    <option value="Counter tops">Counters</option>
    <option value="Bathroom remodeling">Bathrooms</option>
    <option value="Flooring">Floors</option>
    <option value="Lighting">Lights</option>
    <option value="Other">Others</option>                   
</select>
```

Now my problem is, how could I get those values if lets say I select "Floors and Lights" in my contact form. Because in normal select option, I could have a **Project Type: {{var data.projecttype}}** in custom form Email Template. But this one is a multiple select. This is my first time to encounter a problem like this but I can't find a good source as my guide on internet that something a good guide for this. Hope someone could help and guide me with this.

Comment: do you want to handle select box value in php or in javascript .plz let me know..

Comment: @VishalSharma in php coz im quite good on it

Comment: if you are putting this {{var data.projecttype}} in email template then what you are getting ?

Comment: @VishalSharma on my email, result is **Project Type: array**, I think I must create something like controllers for it, but I do not know how to start

Comment: let just try a quick guess use this on email template {{var data.projecttype[]}}...just a guess

Comment: @VishalSharma its empty... actually I tried that already for I think it would do. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up to my mind to create a new phtml, and i just make my own mail and add this code

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$hear = $_POST['hear'];
$projecttype = implode(', ', $_POST['projecttype']);
$comment = $_POST['comment'];


$to      = 'webdev2all@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message =  'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" .
            'E-mail: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
            'Telephone: ' . $telephone . "\r\n" .
            'How did you hear about us: ' . $hear . "\r\n" .
            'Project Type: ' . $projecttype . "\r\n\r\n" .
            'Comment: ' . $comment;
$headers = 'From: '. $name .' '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webdev2all@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

I also change my form action to

```
action="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>"
```

now my contact page form is working as I needed...
thanks for the replies...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get value of multiselect box, you can use jQuery for that. See the below sample code.

```
<select id="multipleSelect" name="projecttype[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="" selected>Select...</option>
    <option value="Kitchen remodeling">Kitchen</option>
    <option value="Refacing">Reface</option>
    <option value="Counter tops">Counters</option>
    <option value="Bathroom remodeling">Bathrooms</option>
    <option value="Flooring">Floors</option>
    <option value="Lighting">Lights</option>
    <option value="Other">Others</option>                   
</select>

<div onclick="javascript:getValues();">TEST ME</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getValues(){
var selectedValues = jQuery('#multipleSelect').val();
alert(selectedValues);//alert if you want to
}
</script>
```

When you click on **TEST ME** `<div>`, you can see the values selected.

The above is a demo code. You can change it as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried in this way...

```
foreach ($_GET['projecttype'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
```